# Combine two find into a single one

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I have two find statements

```
find . -type f -name "*.py[c|o]" -exec rm -f {} +
find . -type d -name  "__pycache__" -exec rm -r {} +
```

I want to know if it is possible to combine both into a single one, if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . '(' ...... ')' -o '(' ..... ')'
```

like

```
find . '(' -type f -name "*.py[c|o]" -exec rm -f {} + ')' -o \
       '(' -type d -name  "__pycache__" -exec rm -r {} + ')'
```